# Aptana returns "Malformed \uxxxx encoding." when debugging with PHP 5.4.x

Tags: aptana

When I try to debug or run a PHP script on my test Windows server using Aptana and PHP 5.4.24 (or the latest 5.4.x, 5.4.40), I am told "Malformed \uxxxx encoding" has occurred.

Given most material online about this error (with any Java code) refers to paths, I've tried installing this PHP version in two locations (and with an additionally different path), with no change. None of the paths contain the string "\u".

If I use PHP 5.5.12 instead, there's no error.

My production server uses 5.4.24, and I would prefer to leave it the way it is for the time being. I would like to debug using the same version of PHP.

A certain Igor appears to have had the same problem as me in July 2014: http://php.tutorialhorizon.com/how-to-debug-php-in-aptana-studio/#comment-2225

The offered solution "check your paths" hasn't helped me.

Log:

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-21 13:44:19.026
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching website".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at org2.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.XDebugExeLaunchConfigurationDelegate.isXDebugFunctional(XDebugExeLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:310)
    at org2.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.XDebugExeLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(XDebugExeLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:86)
    at org2.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.launching.PHPLaunchDelegateProxy.launch(PHPLaunchDelegateProxy.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the property file or the file displayed in the error message and change the backslash to forwardslash:

...\user_projects... to .../user_projects...
Or
...\uxxxx... to .../uxxxx...

\u is a reserved keyword and throws the system off.

Note: "..." and "xxxx" are depicting anything in this case. Usually the error displays a line number one line below the actual line with the issue or so-called ...\u...

Reference: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6555979

It is really disappointing that so many of these issues with java plague many of us and so many articles send people on a wild goose chase. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are there paths with **/u**sr in them somewhere? The windows version of PHP can do odd things with slashes and backslashes. Without seeing your config it is hard to say.

Comment: What further details would you like to know? Apatana itself is installed in a location including "\users\"... I will try it in another location.

Comment: Sometimes you need to put in the backslashes as \\ instead so they escape themselves. Might try that if you have the path listed somewhere.

Comment: I can't find any PHP settings with "\u" in any paths. I've moved Aptana to a location without any "\u" in the path, and the error continues to occur.